# Balancing Legacy CRM Needs and Security in Multiple Databases

Tags: sql-server, database-design, permissions

I have a set of databases on a server.

- Database_alpha
- Database_beta
- Database_gamma
- Database_delta

Database_alpha houses a legacy CRM system which has an inbuilt dependency on the **sa** account to function. Problem is that overtime the **db_owner** of each database has been assigned to **sa**.

One mitigation that seems for at least is to enable the **sa** account for database_alpha so that any system\crm work can be carried out then. It improves on the current situation.

So what is the norm for other database owners. I know it has to be an account of least privilege at least and the name for each database be like this. Is something like this acceptable. Can the accounts then be disabled.

- Database_alpha    *sa*
- Database_beta     *Database_beta_8fe0eaf0*
- Database_gamma    *Database_gamma_9b253adb*
- Database_delta    *Database_delta_d8ed5661*

Appreciate your views or alternate strategies or general suggestions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: And clarify why you're worried about having sa as the owner of all the databases.

Comment: Mainly because we recently had SQL Server Vulns: VA2201, VA1058, VA1258 & VA2108 come across our desks for our SQL Server where these databases are held. We inherited the DB from the service supplier so it was pre-configured so now we have to hit these as part of internal audit responsibilities. So the goal is to close off these and also use it as a chance to implement best practice.